# Variety and rational function.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety and $K = k(X),$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $A$ be open in $X$ and $\{A_i\}$ is an open covering of $A.$ Let $f\in k(X)$ with $f = 0$ on $A_i.$ How do we prove that $f = 0$ on $A.$ This seems simple but I am just in the learning phase. Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean the function field $k(X)$? Because $k(X) \to k(A_i)$ is an isomorphism (if $A_i$ is non-empty, otherwise $k(A_i)$ is not declared), there is nothing to show. Or do you mean the coordinate ring $k[X]$? How do you define it? (There are various definitions, of course they all turn out to be equivalent. I have to ask this because with some definitions there is again nothing to show.)

Comment: I changed {$A_i$} to $\{A_i\}$.  That is standard usage and avoids font mismatches and infelicitous spacing.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Michael. Here the coordinate ring $k[X] = k[x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n}]/I(X)$ and $k(X)$ is the function field.

Comment: Yeah but then nothing has to be proven. If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of a variety (or integral scheme) $X$, then $k(U)=k(X)$.

Comment: @ Martin, thank you. This makes sense.